# Переполнение буфера в '' fs_buff, почему и как его избежать

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

```
void removeWhiteSpace(char *string)     
{   
    char *outPtr = string;      
    while (TRUE) {      
        if (*string == 0) {...}     
        else if (*string != ' ' && *string != '\t' && *string != '\n')      
        *(outPtr++) = *(string++);      
    else    
        string++;   
    }       
}
void Data(const char* data, int len)        
{

    int nn = 0;     
    char *fs_buff = new char[len+1];        
    for ( nn=0; nn<len+1; nn++ ) fs_buff[nn] = '\0';        
    strncpy (fs_buff, data, len);       
    removeWhiteSpace (fs_buff);     
    if (strlen (fs_buff) == 0 )         
    {   
       delete [] fs_buff;   
       return;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Отсутствует выход из бесконечного цикла в removeWhiteSpace, в результате указатель outPtr выходит за границы буфера и происходит запись непонятно чего непонятно куда.

Comment: if (*string == 0) { *outPtr = 0; 
     return;}все равно буфер переполняется\

Comment: @Vazgen H.  Что вы имеете в виду под переполнением буфера?

Comment: @VazgenH. Давайте вы будете писать ВЕСЬ код?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Там легко может быть выход за границы буфера: в removeWhiteSpace не стоит проверки на длину строк.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов  Функция хоть и написана коряво, тем не менее корректная.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, на самом деле неизвестно, что скрывается за `{...}` в removeWhiteSpace. Если `{*outPtr = 0; return;}`, то корректная. / Автор, КАК Вы поняли (или с чего решили), что у Вас переполнение fs_buff? В том виде, как Вы представили код, там утечка (если буфер не пуст), а как Вы переполнение нашли?

Comment: в буфере нет '\0'

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Она некорректна: выход из функции осуществляется только при нахождении нулевого байта во входной строке. Если его нет в пределах выделенного буфера - указатели уйдут за него.

Comment: @VazgenH. Как раз вы заносите в буфер 0. Как вы определили, что там нет нуля? Составьте из ваших функций минимальную программу, которая воспроизводит ошибку.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в Data() корявенько, но обеспечивается завершение буфера нулем. `for ( nn=0; nn<len+1; nn++ ) fs_buff[nn] = '\0';        
    strncpy (fs_buff, data, len);` / Автор, как Вы увидели, что там нет нуля? По идее он должен там присутствовать (если передаваемый в Data() len >= 0)

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов  Все правильно. Так и должны быть, то есть выход по завершающему 0.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow По идее - да, присутствует, но если его там нет и есть хоть один пробел - removeWhiteSpace будет коряво работать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Функция предназначена для работы со строками, и она работает корректно.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, исправьте орфографическую ошибку в тегах, вы новый тег создали.

Comment: @Ivan Solntsev Я выбрал правильную мету, а как удалить случайно созданную, не знаю. Наверное это должны сделать модераторы.